# How to check mapped network drive if exist by hostname C#

Tags: c#, mapped-drive

I have a problem in my code C#. I can not check mapped network drive if exist by host name. I can check by ip address with ping function. But actual problem is not ip address. I need to check a hostname.

```
Ping ping = new Ping(); 
var reply = ping.Send("ADS-201"); 
if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success) { 
  NetworkDrive oNetDrive = new NetworkDrive(); 
  oNetDrive.LocalDrive = "Z:"; 
  oNetDrive.ShareName = "\\\\ADS-201\\fileserver\\public"; 
  oNetDrive.MapDrive(); 
}
```

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far. Thanks

Comment: Showing there is basic network connectivity (ping) would be only the first step to be able to use a mapped drive (far more of the networking stack is needed). Could you clarify why you are doing this (and what you mean by "check": existence or something more). Want to avoid an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Ping ping = new Ping();
            var reply = ping.Send("ADS-201");
            if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
                NetworkDrive oNetDrive = new NetworkDrive();
                oNetDrive.LocalDrive = "Z:";
                oNetDrive.ShareName = "\\\\ADS-201\\fileserver\\public";
                oNetDrive.MapDrive();
            }

Comment: Please describe exactly what is failing: there are no IP addresses in the code.

Comment: I am trying to check ADS-201 hostname if exists: IF(mapped drive ==" ADS-201")

Answer (score 0):

This was an answer: My friend figure it out, I am just sharing who needs it.

```
 var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
            "root\\CIMV2",
             "SELECT * FROM Win32_MappedLogicalDisk");
            List<string> gunler = new List<string>();
 try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(60 * 1 * 100);
                    gunler.Clear();
                    foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
                    {
                        gunler.Add(queryObj["ProviderName"].ToString().Substring(2,7));
                        //MessageBox.Show("Caption: " + queryObj["ProviderName"] + " ---" + queryObj["FileSystem"]);
                    }

                    // Console.WriteLine("*** calling MyMethod *** ");
                    IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.123");
                    //IPAddress hostn = IPAddress.Parse("ADS-201");
                    Ping ping = new Ping();
                    var reply = ping.Send(ip);
                   // var hosreply = ping.Send(hostn);
                    if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                    {

                        if (gunler.Contains("ads-201") || gunler.Contains("ADS-201"))
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("ADS-201 is exist");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("ADS-201 does not exist!");

                        }



                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("No ping to hostname!");
                    }
                   // yuor_method();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
           }
```